# Pointer returns

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am solving a coding challenge.  In this challenge, we would be given two linked lists (2 -> 4 -> 3) and (5 -> 6 -> 4) and we have to return the result of their addition (7 -> 0 -> 8).

While I did solve it, I found a better version on Google:

```
ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
    ListNode preHead(0), *p = &preHead;
    int extra = 0;
    while (l1 || l2 || extra) {
        int sum = (l1 ? l1->val : 0) + (l2 ? l2->val : 0) + extra;
        extra = sum / 10;
        p->next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        p = p->next;
        l1 = l1 ? l1->next : l1;
        l2 = l2 ? l2->next : l2;
    }
    return preHead.next;
}
```

However, I don't understand the step `ListNode preHead(0), *p = &preHead;`.  The address of `preHead` is being stored in the pointer variable `p`.  In other words, `p` points to `preHead`.  Then, why is `preHead.next` being returned in the end?  Note that this code does compile and return the expected output.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: The loop is constructing a new linked list, and using `preHead.next` to point to the first node in that list.  `p` is simply the pointer it uses to track the current node (which, before the loop, points at `preHead`, but in the loop points at the last node in the list.    Incidentally, that code is overly cryptic, so I wouldn't characterise it as a particularly good solution.

Comment: Thank you!  If `preHead->next` points to the first node at the beginning, then aren't we increasing it (by `p=p->next`)?  How does it point to the head of the list at the end?

Comment: `p` is a distinct variable from `preHead`.   Although initialised to `&preHead`, the assignment `p = p->next` changes `p` (to make it point to the next object in the list).   It does not affect change `preHead`.

Comment: I still don't understand the ```prehead(0)```. is this like an adrdess setting, or pointing to the start of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to call it the Dummy Node Pattern. It's where the user will construct an unused node for the purpose of making things like insertion and lookup a lot easier to implement. As you can see in the function, `p` already points to a valid node to begin with, so there is no need to check if `p` is `NULL` and set it to a node of this is true, rather we just append a node using `p->next`. This is the alternative code where `p`'s starting value is `NULL`:

```
ListNode* p = nullptr;
ListNode* tail;
while (l1 || l2 || extra) {
    //int sum = (l1 ? l1->val : 0) + (l2 ? l2->val : 0) + extra;
    //extra = sum / 10;
    if (p != nullptr) {
        tail->next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        tail = tail->next;
    } else {
        tail = p = new ListNode(sum % 10);
    }
    //l1 = l1 ? l1->next : l1;
    //l2 = l2 ? l2->next : l2;
}
return p;
```

We would have to keep an extra pointer to the end of the list so we know where to insert at each iteration. And we have to make sure `p` is not a null pointer in the case of inserting for the first time.

The reason `preHead.next` is returned is because `preHead.next` is where the insertion begins (it is the head of the actual linked list we want to return).

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
p->next =new ListNode(sum % 10);
```

Allocates the new node that is returned.

In the first iteration of the loop, `*p` is the same as `preHead`. Later iterations move `p`, but do not invalidate `preHead` holding a pointer to the first new element added.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But, my question is, how does `preHead.next` point to the new Linked List that is being created?

Answer (score 0):

> Then, why is `preHead.next` being returned in the end?

Because `addTwoNumbers` returns a pointer but `preHead` is a stack variable (i.e. a temporary); returning a temporary reference as a pointer to be de-referenced later is undefined behavior.

However, `preHead.next` is a heap allocated variable and can then be properly de-referenced when it needs to be.